# Is that jar file required or how the apk file executed in android virtual device?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Recently I downloaded the 'android-1.5-cupcake-src.zip' (android source), Can anybody mention the jar file( I mention 'android-1.5-cupcake-src' is for a sample,consider it as a general case  ) name corresponding to that source file(ie the implementation jar of 'android.jar' api-android.jar api contains only abstract classes-)? Is that specific jar(if exist) used for android apk file execution? Or is any dex file version of that jar exist? I know there is no class file included in the 'apk' archive. But then how the dex code executed? How the android emulator runs(interacts) with the apk file with out presence of  such a jar or dex file? Is DVM byte(?) code can directly interact with dex file to execute the code.I search a lot through the android SDK installation directory for that particular jar file but no result!!. Is that code(jar) never used in any state of android app formation(dex file creation/conversion may possible with android.jar api but how the execution is possible)?  If there is no jar(dex?) file exist then what is importance of publishing such a source?

Answer (score 1):

1. Downloading 'android-1.5-cupcake-src.zip' in 2012 is a bit too late, because we already have android-4.0 and android-5.0 will come out soon. The population of devices using android-1.5 is less than 0.5%, so, please, develop for something more contemporary.
2. You don't need source code for the mainstream development. Basically, you have to [install SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html), Eclipse and [development tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html), and you are all set for development.
3. Browse through SDK samples if you need an inspiration.

Comment: actually I am now developing an android app using android api 8, during the development I curious about the execution flow of android apk file. So I install a decompiler plug-in in eclipse.I explore through android.jar api file attached to the project,but it contains full of abstract classes, then I search through net for actual implementation code, I found android-1.5-cupcake-src.zip(I don't know how to download the latest version code through git) and I downloaded it for just study.

Comment: you may [download source code for Android 4.0](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html), if you like, or you might prefer to read [Technical Info regarding Dalvik interpreter](http://source.android.com/tech/index.html) instead. Also, there is [information about odexing/deodexing](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6925/what-is-the-difference-between-odexed-and-deodexed-roms), explaining the process.